# PHP pregmatch utf8 (scandinavian chars)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm having a problem modifying an old preg_match code.

The current code is

```
if (empty($name) || preg_match('#[^\w-\'\"\s]#si', $name)) {
```

But this blocks utf8 signs, in my case å æ ø.

Whats the easiest way to validate them ?

Comment: try: `/#[^\w-\'\"\s]#si/u'

Comment: add the `/u` modifier to enable UTF matching.

Comment: problem with /u is that once i add this, it allows åæø.
But signs like <?php> is also okayed

so it breaks the rex?

Answer (score 0):

You can look for unicode letters if PCRE was installed with `--enable-unicode-properties` you use `\p{L}` instead of `\w`

See the documentation on unicode characters in regex on the PHP site https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Comment: preg_match('#[^\P{L}\'\"\s]#si', $name)) {

still gives me an error

Comment: should be a lowercase p I've edited my answer, uppercase P negates.

Comment: Hi i edited it to lowercase, but still gives me an invalid char if i add å æ ø

Answer (score 0):

add the u modifier http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

> u (PCRE_UTF8):
>
> This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern strings are treated as UTF-8. This modifier is available from PHP 4.1.0 or greater on Unix and from PHP 4.2.3 on win32. UTF-8 validity of the pattern is checked since PHP 4.3.5.

Comment: took your advise and added the u for utf8, it does validate now but is my syntax ok ?

if (empty($name) || preg_match('#[^\w-\'\"\s\u]#si', $name)) {

Comment: You should remove \u from inside the class, I think there is no such thing, and maybe add a \ before -

Comment: preg_match('#[^\w\-\'\"\s]#sui', $name);

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i actually tried the same but it still gives me error when i add åæø 

Ill paste the whole function
if (empty($name) || preg_match('#[^\w\-\'\"\s]#sui', $name)) {
  $errors[] = "Invalid/empty name";
    }

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten your regex pattern because I don't think you want to include the numbers that come with `\w`.  I have added a large range of accented letter that should cover all of the Scandinavian characters that you might encounter.

I have removed the test for `empty()` since the regex pattern requires a minimum of 1 character.

To view a table of characters and their unicode numbers, visit https://unicode-table.com/en/

You can view and experiment with my regex pattern at this [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eYHg5L/1) to make sure you are including all valid characters for your project.

Here is my [PHP Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d2a88136f46cb69c3f7a45a3b429b366064414ff) -- also useful for testing some of your actual input names.

Test Code:

```
$names=array(
    "Fred"=>"Fred",
    "T3d"=>"T3d",
    "null"=>null,
    "empty"=>"",
    "Babe The Bambino Ruth"=>'Babe "The Bambino" Ruth',
    "Bjorg"=>"Björg",
    "Shawniqua"=>"Shawn'iq-ua",
    "Abjorn"=>"Åbjørn",
    "Mary-Jane"=>"Mary-Jane",
    "Will.i.am"=>"Will.i.am",
    "AEstrid"=>"Æstrid");

foreach($names as $key=>$name){
    if(preg_match('/^[A-Z\x{C0}-\x{2AF}\'"\s-]+$/sui',$name)){
        $goodies[]="Valid: $name";
    }else{
        $errors[]="Invalid/empty name: $key";
    }
}
echo "Valids:\n";
var_export($goodies);
echo "\n\nInvalids:\n";
var_export($errors);
```

Output:

```
Valids:
array (
  0 => 'Valid: Fred',
  1 => 'Valid: Babe "The Bambino" Ruth',
  2 => 'Valid: Björg',
  3 => 'Valid: Shawn\'iq-ua',
  4 => 'Valid: Åbjørn',
  5 => 'Valid: Mary-Jane',
  6 => 'Valid: Æstrid',
)

Invalids:
array (
  0 => 'Invalid/empty name: T3d',
  1 => 'Invalid/empty name: null',
  2 => 'Invalid/empty name: empty',
  3 => 'Invalid/empty name: Will.i.am',
)
```